# Как получить содержимое тега <h3> в <div class="about">?

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Получил страницу сайта. В ней есть следующая строка

```
<div class="about"> <h3>Алиса</h3>
```

Нужно получить "Алиса". Как это сделать с помощью регулярного выражения?

Сделал следующее: `<div class="about"><h3>(.*)</h3>`

где:

> (...) Группировка (группа)
>
> .    Любой символ (символ точки)
>
> - Ноль и более раз a
>
> x Игнорировать пробелы
>
> \s    Пробельный символ (в т.ч. табуляция)

Но [uvsoftium.ru](http://uvsoftium.ru/php/regexp.php) не хочет определять... Почему?

Дальнейшие действия хочу производить через `preg_match_all`:

```
preg_match_all('#<div class="about"><h3>(.*)</h3>#x', $content[$i], $matches[$i][1], PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Результатом возвращает пустой массив.

Comment: не первый ваш вопрос про то как извлечь данные из страницы. используйте для этих целей соответствующие инструменты, например, phpQuery, а не регулярные выражения

Comment: Опишите подробнее.  как вы это себе представляете?

Comment: `@doox911` дополнил ответ

Comment: пропустили пробел в выражении `<div class="about"> <h3>`,

Comment: `@Spartacus` испробовал <div class="about">(\s*)<h3>(.*)</h3>. Всё равно получаю пустой массив и сервис его тоже не видет

Comment: `@Spartacus` забыл указать это в вопросе. В моем регулярном выражении `#<div class="about"><h3>(.*)</h3>#x`, `#x`  означает игнорировать пробелы.

Comment: проверьте что у вас в `$content[$i]`, через `var_dump($content[$i])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае проблема в символе `/`. Он является служебным, и его необходимо экранировать: `\/`.

Так же в исходной строке между `<div class="about">` и `<h3>` присутствует пробел, который не учитывается в вашем регулярном выражении. Пробельные символы могут быть разные, поэтому для пространства пробельных символов есть специальная конструкция `\s`.

Для вашей группы я бы советовал использовать *жадный* алгоритм поиска: `<h3>(.*?)</h3>`. Т.к. в вашем случае в исходном тексте вида: `<div class="about"> <h3>Алиса</h3> <h3>Лена</h3> </div>`, будет найдено: `Алиса</h3> <h3>Лена`.

Итого выражение: `/<div class="about">\s*<h3>(.*?)<\/h3>/`.

Скорее всего я не учёл все проблемы. Но надеюсь я ответил на ваш вопрос.

Comment: `/` не надо экранировать, так как в качестве ограничителей используется `#`

Comment: Но сайт [uvsoftium.ru](http://uvsoftium.ru/php/regexp.php) использует `/`. Вопрос же возник из-за того, что это выражение не работает на этом сайте.

Comment: В вопросе в примере между тем `#`